# ptor.findElements always returns true

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have the following Code, which never runs the error portion

```
   ptor.findElements(protractor.By.css(elementCss)).then(function (elems) {
                                element = elems;
                                elementFound = true;
                               // if element.all(...).count()
                                console.log("inside then clause , Element Found");
                            }, function (err) {
                                console.error("waiting for element( " + elementCss + " ) to be found " + currentCount + "/" + timeout);
                            }); //ptor.findElement
```

even if the elementCss ='abc', some junk value, it always resolve into then clause
and not into reject/error as that is a junk css name.

findElement on the other hand behaves as expected. am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API for *findElement* returns en error if the element is not found by the given selector.

The API for *findElements* is to return an empty list if the selector does not match any element.

From findElement [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html) :

```
If the element cannot be found, a bot.ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT result will be returned by the driver
```